# Change build setting's PRODUCT_BUNDLE_ID dynamically

Tags: ios, fastlane

I would like to know how can the PRODUCT_BUNDE_ID from Build Settings can be changed dynamically before compiling and building an app. I am using fastlane and I change the CFBundleIdentifier with update_info_plist but this does not change the PRODUCT_BUNDLE_ID in the build settings too. As I understand this cannot be achieved in this way starting with xCode7. Can anyone guide me for another way of solving this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just as you update the plist value, update the xcodeproj/xcworkspace file as well. There are a variety of ways to achieve this but personally I have:

1. Simply parse the files where the value needs updated and perform a gsub or other type injection to update the file.

Example:

```
File.write(file_with_value, File.open(file_with_value,&:read).gsub(/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER/, updated_bundle_id))
```

That will simply read the file, find every occurrence of `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` and replace it with the value you provide. *warning: this can create problems depending on your configuration*

2. Use one of a variety of fastlane plugins to handle this action for you. Most recent/popular option appears to be: https://github.com/Mindera/fastlane-plugin-cosigner